# TLS handshake error but only on mobile page refresh when accessing camera

Tags: android, google-chrome, go, ssl, webrtc

I'm working on an app that can stream webcam video from any browser to a server to (eventually) do some machine learning/ocr stuff without having to download any native apps or programs

It's currently up and running using WebRTC to connect to an https Golang server running on AWS. Port 443 is exposed and all that.

However, since it uses a self-signed SSL certificate you have to click proceed when chrome throws up a warning. Once you click through the app works fine on Desktop all the time and mobile the first time you visit the site.

My problem though is that when I try and revisit/refresh the page from my phone (chrome on android) the byte stream from the camera normally displayed in the ec2 terminal freezes and I get:

`TLS handshake error from X.X.X.X: remote error: tls: unknown certificate`

If I clear the camera permissions and reload I have to click through the warning again but the byte stream unfreezes

Is there a way to fix the refresh problem or will it always be an issue for android using as long as I use self-signed certificates?

Edit: Not at a computer but considering the possibility chrome for Android isn't releasing the camera stream correctly so the connection can't be restablished?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use a real certificate. This is easy enough (and free) these days.